# How are blocking calls like database access handled internally by a Jetty Non Blocking IO servlet?

Tags: java, node.js, jetty, nonblocking

I have read a lot of material to try and clearly understand the gains a Jetty Non Blocking Web Application Server can or can't offer.

So far what I understand (in part by referring to this: [How do Jetty and other containers leverage NIO while sticking to the Servlet specification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25195128/how-do-jetty-and-other-containers-leverage-nio-while-sticking-to-the-servlet-spe)) is that with a non blocking IO model a web server like Jetty runs a single (or one per CPU core) thread - the Selector thread - that determines connections that are ready for some I/O. Connections that are ready with some I/O are dispatched for processing on to an internal thread pool to process the request.

I can see how such an architecture could allow you to serve many more connections with far fewer resources. However, what I am not clear about is this:

If I wrote a servlet that ran a long running database operation using a standard JDBC driver performing blocking I/O, wouldn't the handler thread  dispatched from the pool to handle this request block?

And if requests came through faster than database requests are fulfilled, the handler thread pool would exhaust at some point?

And so with an application such as this is there any benefit to be run on a Non Blocking Jetty webserver? Is the non-blocking benefit only truly accrued if the servlet itself used another layer of non-blocking access to the database? Or is there something I am missing?

Please do explain if there's some magic through which Jetty will pay less of a price for the blocking database operations than say, a blocking web server.

P.S: For a contrast I read about Node.js here - [How the single threaded non blocking IO model works in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795145/how-the-single-threaded-non-blocking-io-model-works-in-node-js) - it seems to suggest that Node uses libuv underneath and applies other techniques to translate all blocking operations in code (such as database access and `sleep()`) into event callbacks ensuring the event loop and the internal thread pool never  get blocked in a blocking callback. While it's still a little gobbledygook to me, but assuming that's true for Node, can Jetty promise the same? That too for servlets etc that are not written in a non-blocking way?